# Cannot run Unicorn with Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, ruby-2.0

On my ubuntu machine, I can run unicorn on ruby 1.9.3, however, it does not seem to work with ruby 2.0. Any idea why?

```
root@dev:/home/karan# rvm use 1.9
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
root@dev:/home/karan# unicorn -v
unicorn v4.6.3
root@dev:/home/karan# rvm use 2.0
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
root@dev:/home/karan# unicorn -v
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- unicorn/launcher (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/unicorn:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you do `bundle install` after you switched ruby version?

Comment: I wasn't inside a rails folder ...

Comment: I think the problem is that the unicorn was installed in 1.9.3 and when you attempt to use it with 2.0.0, it breaks. You'd have to reinstall the gem in 2.0.0 to work it with 2.0.0.

Comment: ok, will try it out right now. I have a feeling you're right ...

Comment: and you were! add it as an answer, and I will gladly mark it as accepted! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reinstalling the gem with 2.0.0.

The problem must have been caused by the fact the gem was installed in 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same problem when I try to start Unicorn server

```
Starting Unicorn web server unicorn
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- unicorn/launcher (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' from /usr/bin/unicorn:3:in `<main>'
```

Nevertheless, Unicorn works fine when I run it from the rails app folder, simply using "unicorn" command.

I have tried what you suggest, installing the gem unicorn

```
gem install 'unicorn'
```

But it does not change the result

I check what gem is installed:

```
which gem 'unicorn'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/gem
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn
```

I am running unicorn from a etc/init.d script that you can see here:

http://pastebin.com/qvwdmRJ2

and here for the default configuration:

http://pastebin.com/84FBQjMp

There seems to be some problem with the PATH of the default configuration file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/home/unicorn/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:$
```

Because since I updated it with the new installed version I get the error message shown at the top. If I remove it, Unicorn "apparently starts" but the log shows a crazy activity and nginx shows an empty screen.

I am trying to find a solution and will share it here as soon as I find it.

Thanks for your help

* UPDATE ***

OK I have found the problems:

1) for the /etc/init.d script:

You need to create a wrapper for Unicorn to work in a init.d type of script:

rvm wrapper 2.0.0 ruby-2.0.0 unicorn

then replace the line

DAEMON=/usr/bin/unicorn

with this one:

DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby-2.0.0_unicorn

And now the command

service unicorn start

more on rvm wrapper here: https://rvm.io/integration/init-d

2) I also had another issue that was difficult to identify in the log:

I had not created a config/environments/staging.rb file