# Does Unicorn Support Ruby 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, unicorn, ruby-2.0

I'm designing a new Rails4 stack, and trying to decide on Passenger Vs. Unicorn.

I'm excited about finally building a new Ruby 2.X app, but the Unicorn webpage doesn't list support for Ruby 2. Is that crazy?

http://unicorn.bogomips.org

If there's 'hacks' for Ruby 2 support, are they 3rd party hacks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193506/cannot-run-unicorn-with-ruby-2-0

Answer (score 1):

Unicorn supports Ruby 2.0 out of the box.

We've been running unicorn/rainbows on Ruby 2.0 in production for a year or so.

Comment: Can you find any documentation that supports this statement?